# The header of a new chapter is shown in the last page of the previous chapter

Tags: header-footer

I faced the following problem while writing my thesis. I am using a Latex template on Overleaf that includes "fancyhdr" package for adding the chapters' header on the top-left part of the page (here the project in case: https://it.overleaf.com/1433821482pvjkxhmrvwnh). However, the last page of each chapter has the header reporting the name of the next chapter. Unfortunately, I don't know the exact name of the template, as a colleague of mine gave it to me several year ago. By the way, here's the Main (.tex) file:

```
% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" 
%style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage{placeins} % put this in your pre-amble
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use 
%the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page 
numbering

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{Ph.D. DEGREE IN ...}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.5}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger 
%line spacing than the other way round

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for 
%one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page 
%number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to 
%implement the FancyHdr headers
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{Contents}}  % Set the left side page header to 
%"Contents"
\tableofcontents  % Write out the Table of Contents
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}}  % Set the left side page header to 
%"List if Figures"
\listoffigures  % Write out the List of Figures
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}}  % Set the left side page header to 
%"List of Tables"
\listoftables  % Write out the List of Tables
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

% End of the pre-amble, contents and lists of things
% Begin the Dedication page

\setstretch{1.5}  % Return the line spacing back to 1.5
\pagestyle{empty}  % Page style needs to be empty for this page
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for 
%aesthetics

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter   % Begin normal, numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy}  % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" 
%style

% Include the chapters of the thesis, as separate files
% Just uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\input{Chapters/Chapter1} 

\input{Chapters/Chapter2}

\input{Chapters/Chapter3}


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}  % Change the left side page header to 
%"Bibliography"
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for 
%formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{Bibliography}  % The references (bibliography) 
%information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}  % The End
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Every input chapter starts with these lines:

```
\lhead{\emph{Chapter number "x"}}
\chapter{Chapter number "x"}
```

This is not a working example because files .sty and .cls are missing (and also the input chapters). However, if I compile this, at page 3 (end of chapter 1) I already see the header of the next chapter, which, however, is in the next page.
Should I provide additional information in order to help me figuring this out? Thanks

Comment: Please don't post links to Overleaf projects that require log in. Questions here should be self-contained. Not all of us have, or want, Overleaf accounts. At the very least, post the name of the template so we can search for it on CTAN or github or elsewhere if we don't want to use Overleaf.

Comment: "However, the last page of each chapter has the header reporting the name of the next chapter." That could indicate that `fancyhdr` parameters are changed before the `\chapter` command instead of after it. Because then you are still on the. previous page. By the way, there is usually no need to change the headers manually. They can be obtained from the "marks".

Comment: @frabjous Thank you, and sorry for the Overleaf link. I edited my question, to try and keep it here. I don't know the name of the template, but I hope the attached code could help.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum many thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I also think fancyhdr parameters changed somehow. Still, I am not able to understan what is going on. But I will try again.

Comment: Thanks. However, we still cannot test your code without `Thesis.cls`. (It annoys me that Overleaf normalizes the use of document classes and packages not on CTAN.) Anyway, one should not use new `\lhead` commands before every chapter. It's better to use LaTeX's marking mechanisms (See the [fancyhdr documentation](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).) Something like: `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}\lhead{\textit{\rightmark}}` *once* in the preamble. If you insist on doing a new `\lhead` every chapter, put a `\clearpage` before it.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks a lot, it worked! Unfortunately, I'm in a hurry to deliver my thesis, and so I just added `\clearpage` before `\lhead`. Now the document is perfect, but I will improve it once I receive the first thesis revision. Again, thank you very much!